# VBA Automation - Div object is not clickable

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, automation, click

I'm currently creating a web automation in VBA. I'm having difficulties of clicking a 'div' component -> it is not responding to any click,onclick,mousedown...etc. events.
I was able to "catch" the div component as an object in VBA but when I try these actions it is not responding to any of it. Also its internal components as well.

The div object:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="SubForm SubForm-up" role="button" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 140px; height: 26px; float: right;">
<input tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: -1; opacity: 0;" type="text">
<div class="html-face">הגדרות לחשבון מעבר</div>
</div>
```

My code:

```
Set frmPane = doc.getElementsByClassName("SubForm SubForm-up")(3)
       frmPane.onclick = frmPane.onmousedown
       frmPane.onclick = frmPane.onmouseup
       
       With frmPane
            .Focus
            '.setAttribute "display", "block"
            '.setAttribute "aria-expanded", "true"
            .Click
            .onclick = frmPane.onmouseup
            .FireEvent "onclick"
            .FireEvent "onmouseover"
            .FireEvent "onmousedown"
            .FireEvent "onmouseup"
            .FireEvent "onkeydown"
            .FireEvent "onkeypress"
            .FireEvent "onkeyup"
           ' .Blur
        End With
        
       
       Set heshbonMaavarObj = frmPane.getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
       With heshbonMaavarObj
            .Focus
            .Click
            .FireEvent "onclick"
            .FireEvent "onmouseover"
            .FireEvent "onmousedown"
            .FireEvent "onmouseup"
            .FireEvent "onkeydown"
            .FireEvent "onkeypress"
            .FireEvent "onkeyup"
            '.Blur
        End With
       
       Set heshbonMaavarObj = frmPane.getElementsByTagName("div")(0)
       With heshbonMaavarObj
            .Focus
            .Click
            .FireEvent "onclick"
            .FireEvent "onmouseover"
            .FireEvent "onmousedown"
            .FireEvent "onmouseup"
            .FireEvent "onkeydown"
            .FireEvent "onkeypress"
            .FireEvent "onkeyup"
            '.Blur
        End With
```

Comment: <div tabindex="0" class="SubForm SubForm-up" role="button" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 140px; height: 26px; float: right;">
<input tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: -1; opacity: 0;" type="text">
<div class="html-face">הגדרות לחשבון מעבר</div>
</div>

Comment: I paste the html code both in the question and as comment because it seems to disappear from the question section.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I created a simple example to test, and I find inline scripts can work very well. What do you mean by not responding? Can you provide more details?

This is my test(using window.alert() function):

```
Sub TriggerDivClick()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim div As HTMLDivElement
    Dim url As String

    url = "https://localhost:44315/Index.html"
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set doc = ie.document
    Set div = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("SubForm SubForm-up")(0)
    div.FireEvent "onclick"
    ie.Quit

    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub

<div tabindex="0" class="SubForm SubForm-up" role="button" aria-pressed="false" style="width: 140px; height: 26px; float: right;" onclick="window.alert('Div element clicked...')">
        <input tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: -1; opacity: 0;" type="text">
        <div class="html-face">הגדרות לחשבון מעבר</div>
    </div>
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is that this 'div' "sits" in a pane which is also a div, inside a table. When I wrote not responding I meant that I fire all these click events to this div and I don't get the result as I perform a click by mouse. Is that clear enough?

Comment: If this is the case, I think the problem may be related to the page structure. Can you provide a link for this page, or the complete page structure code so that we can reproduce the issue? This will help solve the problem.

Comment: I cannot provide a link to this page. It's an external system which I cannot reach its source code

Comment: It may be that some page element attributes have changed after the click event. In this case, you need to manually change the element code. And you mentioned the `internal components`, I think this should use some framework, so if there is no code that can reproduce this issue, I am afraid I can not determine the cause of this issue and solve it. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks. I also think it uses a framework and I can reach its source. I really appreciate your effort.